# Python: argparse taking a list of variable size

Tags: python, input, argparse

In Python, using `argparse`, I want an input argument to take a **variable number** of files, like:

```
$ myScript --aParameter file1 file2 file3 ... fileN
```

How can do it?

```
parser.add_argument( "--aParameter", nargs=????, type=str,
                        help="Provide a list of files to analyze",
                        default=None)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the kwarg `nargs='+'`.   That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: Or, `nargs='*'` if you want to support the ability to have an empty list.

Comment: Documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs